# Regex to retrieve tabular data using Perl

Tags: arrays, json, regex, perl

I am trying query some data which is in tabular like below,

```
+----------------------------------------------------- MA ESTICKSTS ------------------------------------------------------+
|                                 |    |                               |    |   |   | Opms  | Esticks Delsif  |Baslentelts|
|Name                             |Type|Esticks Permina                |Div |LvL|mde|Loe|Thi|PC|HH|WE|SS|FF|ER|           |
+---------------------------------+----+-------------------------------+----+---+---+---+---+--+--+--+--+--+--+-----------+
|Nuts-and-spices|code2398         |VS  |Msserie_2398                   |2398|7  |br |0  |3  |  |  |  |  |  |  |No         |
|Nuts-and-spices.EP.034330..WERS..|VS  |Msserie_2996                   |2996|7  |br |3  |2  |  |  |  |  |  |  |Ye         |
+---------------------------------+----+-------------------------------+----+---+---+---+---+--+--+--+--+--+--+-----------+
```

Is that anyway to convert this data into JSON array in Perl? Because it would great if i get these data into an associative array.

And also i do not need the table header data. I simply need to extract row data.

Please help me on that!

Comment: Did you try something? Why tagged [tag:php]?

Comment: I am sorry for that! Its removed now...

Comment: Where does the data come from originally? If there's some kind of API for the data source (like [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI) for databases), it would be better to use that than parsing data meant for human consumption.

Comment: It is not by an API. a output from a network device. The output will be always in this format. Particularly the table column wont change and data will be changed based on the device type.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear from the example that the data (below the headers) is close to fixed width parameters. It might be easier to scan the data using those widths to grab the data.

Alternatively the data resides in a large string separated by '|' characters. Why not split the string into an array using the specific character as the delimiter. It might be wise to use trim (using the array method) to clean the data. [No trim is not apart of the stock library. Check the cookbook for better versions of trim.]